# How I can Merge two datatable into one datatable in c#

Tags: c#

I have tow datatables and i want to merge them and want the output like this;

Table1 values:

```
FirstName   LastName    
  AAA         BBB         
  AAA         BBB
```

Table2 values:
*

```
FullName
  CCC
  CCC
```

*

now i want that FullName's value and FirstName's value merge into One column of Firstname
and out should be like that after merging....

```
FirstName   LastName    
  AAA         BBB         
  AAA         BBB         
  CCC
  CCC
```

Both out tables have the column of FirstName and LastName from dtable1 and FullName from dtable2

i have this code in my c# application

```
             DataSet firstGrid = new DataSet();
            DataSet secondGrid = new DataSet();
            DataTable table1 = dataGridView3.DataSource as DataTable;
            DataTable table2 = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;
            DataColumn[] colunm = new DataColumn[table1.Columns.Count];



            DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
           // table3.;
            table3 = table1.Copy();

            table3.Merge(table2);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table3;
```

Comment: there's already an answer in your question - use [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx)...function.

Comment: @Reniuz Probably Yes Merge but then the other table would also need a similar schema

Comment: @V4Vendetta Well as I know `MissingSchemaAction.Add` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Table1

UNION

SELECT FullName AS 'FirstName', NULL AS 'LastName'
FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
for(int i=0;i<dataTable2.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    DataRow drTemp=dataTable1.NewRow();
    drTemp[0]=dataTable2.Rows[i][0];
    drTemp[1]="";
    dataTable1.Rows.Add(drTemp);
}
```

Basically you are inserting fullnames to the table1 first name and with empty value for last name. Finally dataTable1 will be merged with dataTabe2.

Comment: I have these Tables in c# not in database

Comment: Well if you have in two data tables then I think you have to iterate the 2nd data table and it to the first data table row by row. Check edited answer